# ブラウザ起動時にPOSTパラメータをつけて起動

Tags: java

javaアプリケーションからブラウザ(デフォルト設定されているブラウザ)を起動する際に
URLにPOSTパラメータを付与してブラウザを起動させたいのですが、一度どこかのhtml,phpファイルなどでワンクッション(値を受け取ってリダイレクト)などさせないと無理でしょうか。

ワンクッションなどを利用すると、戻るボタンなどが押せてしまうのが、仕様的にあまりよくないように感じてしまい、できればダイレクトで表示させたいと考えています。
またwindows、macともに動くものを検討しています。

Comment: POSTで送りたいデータの形式によるのですが、わかりますか？サイトを指定していただくのでも良いです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。POSTのデータはid=0001&name=testのような形式になります。